# Moving and animating a UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, animation, uiview

I am trying to make a simple animation. I want to move an UIImageView to the right by using [UIView animateWithDuration....

Here is my code:

file.h

```
{
 IBOutlet UIImageView *moveImage;
}
```

file.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //Move Image

    moveImage.center = CGPointMake(moveImage.center.x, moveImage.center.y);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                     animations:^{ moveImage.center = CGPointMake(moveImage.center.x + 60.0, moveImage.center.y); }];

}
```

When I run the iOS Simulator it shows the image at the new x coordinate, but it doesn't
show the animation. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think its autolayout issue. Are you using autolayout?

Comment: No, I'm not using auto layout. I fixed the problem thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You should use  ViewDidAppear Not ViewDidLoad**

ViewDidLoad means View was loaded to memory, but not drawn. So you can't see the animation at that point.

viewDidAppear means View was drawn. So you can animate after view was shown.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];


        moveImage.center = CGPointMake(moveImage.center.x, moveImage.center.y);
        [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                         animations:^{ moveImage.center = CGPointMake(moveImage.center.x + 60.0, moveImage.center.y); }];

}
```